# Updating table row while looping through an associative array

Tags: php, sql

Trying to carry out two SQL queries within the same table (named Product) while iterating through an associative array, the first SQL query is to get Quantity field from the table (Product), to do some calculation, and the second SQL query is to update the Quantity with its new calculated value.

```
   foreach($productQuantities as $product => $quantity){

       $newQnt = 0; 
  
        $stm = $db->connect()->prepare("SELECT quantity FROM product WHERE name=:product");
        $stm->bindValue(':product', $product);
        $stm->execute();

       $row = $stm->fetch();

        $newQnt = $row['quantity'] - $quantity;  // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
      
         
                $stm2 = $db->connect()->prepare("UPDATE product SET quantity=:quantity 
                WHERE name=:product");
                $stm2->bindValue(':product', $product);
                $stm2->bindValue(':quantity', $newQnt);
                $stm2->execute(); 

 }
```

The  $row['quantity'] is always null and gives me the error : Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool.

Comment: Quick glance, row is most likely false. Could either be that the query isn't returning any rows, or $stm fails to execute the query. Try assigning a boolean value to your $stm->execute() line and output the returned boolean of that... if it's false, there's a problem with your query execution.

Comment: I assigned a boolean value to $stm->execute() and it gives me true;

Comment: a there is no loop and the query makes not that much sense, why not update the column drectly

Comment: after your fetch(), var_dump($row), is your query getting anything?

Comment: I agree with @nbk, you're asking for trouble running two queries to do this job. What happens if two users are updating the same product at the same time? You risk only recording one quantity change unless you modify this to either use one query, or to run the two in a transaction. The former is much easier. `update product set quantity = quantity - :quantity where name = :product`.

Comment: the var_dump($row) gives bool(false)

Comment: Yes, combine them in one query would be better idea, thanks for your contribution SerEnder, and droopsnoot